# Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(time_entry_edit_component_TimeEntryEditComponent) /> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm writing chrome extension using React and Typescript. I decided to use MemoryRouter. And I get an error like `Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(time_entry_edit_component_TimeEntryEditComponent) /> outside a <Router>.`
Here is my code of Routing :

```
    import {MemoryRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
    import { TimeEntryEditComponent } from './components/time-entry-edit.component';
     <Router>
            <Switch>
              <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePageComponent} />
                <Route path="/time-entry/:id" component={TimeEntryEditComponent} />
                <Route path="/issue-edit/:id" component={IssueEditComponent} />
              </StoreContext.Provider>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
```

here is how I connect my TimeEnrtyEditComponent:

```
const wrappedComponent = withRouter<TimeEntryEditProps, any>(TimeEntryEditComponent);
export { wrappedComponent as TimeEntryEditComponent  };
```

Thanks in forward!

Answer (score 1):

## You Don't need withRouter

As a direct child of the Router you already have all of the Router methods passed down.

Just skip withRouter and check the props of the component you should see everything you need.

Comment: Checked, I don't have anything connected with routing, actually

Answer (score 0):

Well, my problem was, that in my prev functionality was :

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById("mount"));
    ReactDOM.render(
      <TimeEntryEditComponent
        changeMode={this.changeMode.bind(this)}
        timeEntry={this.state.timeEntry}
      />,
      document.getElementById("mount")
```

Thats why I replaced all my dom with new component, what caused an error

Comment: May I ask which use case requires it to manually mount and unmount your components?

Comment: well, I'm writing chrome extesion and it do not have it's own history, and if you are wring without global store and react-router, u have to do like this